# Single Sign On for multiple Kraken JS applications

Tags: cookies, kraken.js, connect-mongo

I have two `Kraken JS` applications running with `connect-mongo` as middleware for session storage, on two subdomains like one.example.com and two.example.com. 
Both are protected by user login.

How could I implement a SSO feature to my apps?
Maybe setting the session cookie domain to example.com instead of the subdomain?

Comment: That would seem a valid thing to try. Have you? Most SSO principles are usually about distinct domains with an authentication service to manage it. Cookies should be valid for a base domain unless specified explicitly otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was indeed to set the cookie domain to ".example.com" in configs of both apps.

In the configuration file, at

```
"middleware" -> "session" -> "module" -> "arguments" -> "cookie"
```

I added

```
"domain": ".example.com"
```